# OnItemClickListener Problem

Tags: android, listviewitem

i'm creating a lazy load of image in ListView.
i was followed the tutorial from [this source](http://open-pim.com/tmp/LazyList.zip) which i found in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)
It was run successful.

But, when i join the code together with my project then i face a problem. the program was no perform the OnItemClickListener :(

my project have a TabHost and it had 5 tab contents. 2 contents is using the ListActivity and run perfectly.

here is my coding, Main.java:

```
public class ProductListing extends Activity {
ListView list;
MyListAdapter adapter;
Controller c;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
TextView select;

//========== JSON ===========
ArrayList<String> strName = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> strImage = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> strDesc = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> strSize = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONObject jsonObject;  
String[] listItem;
Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            LoadJSON();
            setContentView(R.layout.productlisting_tab);
            list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
            c = new Controller(this);
            adapter=new MyListAdapter(this,this, strName, strImage,strDesc,strSize);
            list.setAdapter(adapter); 
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Item Clicked");
    }
        });


    }

    public void LoadJSON(){
        try {
            InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.premium);
            byte[] buffer;
            buffer = new byte[is.available()];
            while(is.read(buffer) != -1);
            String jsonText = new String(buffer);

            jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonText);
            JSONObject premium_tab = jsonObject.getJSONObject("premium_tab");               

            int totalItem = premium_tab.getInt(".total");
            for (int i = 1; i <= totalItem; i++) {
                JSONObject premium = premium_tab.getJSONObject("premium_"+i);
                String tempName =premium.getString(".name").toString();
                String tempImg = premium.getString(".image").toString();
                String tempDesc = premium.getString(".desc").toString();
                String tempSize = premium.getString(".size").toString();
                strName.add(tempName);
                strImage.add(tempImg);
                strDesc.add(tempDesc);
                strSize.add(tempSize);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
```

MyListAdapter.java:

```
 public MyListAdapter(Context b,Activity a, ArrayList<String> strName, ArrayList<String> strImage,
            ArrayList<String> strDesc, ArrayList<String> strSize) {
    activity = a;
    name = strName;
    image = strImage;
    desc = strDesc;
    size = strSize;        
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return image.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView ProductName,ProductSize, ProductDesc;
    public ImageView ProductIcon;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.productlisting, null);
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.ProductName=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.ProductIcon=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.ProductDesc=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textdesc);
        holder.ProductSize=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textsize);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

    holder.ProductName.setText(name.get(position));
    holder.ProductDesc.setText(desc.get(position));
    holder.ProductIcon.setTag(image.get(position));
    holder.ProductSize.setText(size.get(position));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(image.get(position), activity, holder.ProductIcon);
    return vi;
  }    
}
```

Another class which name ImageLoader.java please refer the source link above.
May i know where is my mistake? i understand my code will very ugly, i'm a new in android please help me to solve the problem. it was stuck me for few days.
your reply is very appreciated !!!

P/S: I'm sorry about my bad english, hope you guys understand what i'm talking about.
Thank you.

Regard
Wynix

Comment: could you explain better your "itemClick does not work"? do you have an error in the logcat? Have you try debugging by adding logs at regular intervals to find where it is not working?

Comment: Don't you think your adapter looks a bit weird? it does not even extend an Adapter class from the Android Framework...

Comment: Hi Sephy thanks for reply, i have no error in logcat and i have try to put "System.out.println("Item Click!")" in OnItemClickListener() function. but the logcat was no print out any single word. About the adapter, it was extends BaseAdapter, i'm sorry miss copy few line..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the problem and solve it. the erroe is on the xml file. in ListView should NOT have

`android:focusable="true";` menthod.

anyway Thanks for trying to fix my problem.
Thanks again.
Cheers!

Regard Wynix

Answer (score 0):

I use a different technique adding event-listeners. In the OnCreate-method i write `btnAdd.setOnClickListener(onAdd);` and adding a stand-alone method to hook up to the event like this:

```
private View.OnClickListener onAdd=new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // your code here
    }
};
```

This makes it easier to search for errors in your code.

From your code, you set the event-listener to the entire list, instead of each individual item. Maybe you should try adding events to individual items instead?

Comment: Hi BennySkogberg, Thanks for reply. Im sorry i still new in android. i not really understand what you mean adding events to individual items. Do you mean i should adding the events to all the items in the listview? i'm sorry about my bad english, hope you understand what im talking about. Thanks

Comment: No need to apologize for your english, I understand you perfectly well :) You have understood me correctly - every item needs to be hooked up to an individual event handler. When you got the first one working as you like, it's easy to get the rest of the items working.

Comment: Thanks again for replying. But i'm creating the item in list style. how to i adding the events to each items? those item is a ArrayList<String> type. 

"list.setadapter(new ArrayList<String>(this, R.layout.productlisting,strName.get(1));"

isn't the way to adding the event to the items? or it had other way?
some example for me will more easy to understand. Thank you